# My contractor placed pvc for my dryer vent. I had to replace the vent cover and I have it sealed but I have a lot of water in that pipe now

Tags: pvc

30 ft to my dryer. I’m cleaning pvc and hit water at 10 feet. House is 13 yo. Why get water now and how do I fix it. I was going to vent under house and collect in a lint trap but I see that’s not good either. Help

Comment: Water likes to flow down hill.  If you have a small slope(about a 1/4" per foot) the water should drain out.  It sounds like you might have a small dip in the pipe and water collects there.

Comment: @crip659 Sounds like an answer to me

Comment: A dryer has moisture it removes from clothes in the vented air. If the pipe is in a cold place, it will condense inside (think "rain", or "dew"). As @crip659 suggests, at least the last few meters of the pipe should slant down towards the outside.